# res.sendFile does not work

Tags: node.js, express

I am using Express 4.13, and I met some problems when I  tried to serve the files:

```
function doServeFile(name, fullpath, res, download) {
    if (fullpath) {
        if (download)
            res.download(fullpath, name);
        else {
            res.sendFile(fullpath, {}, function (err) {
                console.info(err);
            });
        }
    }
    else {
        res.status(404);
    }
}

function serveFile(id, res, download) {
    Model.findById(id).then(file=> {
        var fullPath = Config.uploadDest + "/" + file.path;
        doServeFile(file.filename, fullPath, res, download)
    }).catch(Util.dbErrorHandler);
}
router.get("/:id", function (req, res, next) {
    serveFile(req.params.id, res);
});
router.get("/download/:id", function (req, res, next) {
    serveFile(req.params.id, res, true);
});
```

As the codes shown, once I send request `/1` to the server, it will retrieve the file whose id is `1` to get the file path, and then use the `res.sendFile` to serve the file to client.

However when I run the application, I found that the request will hang on too long to have the response. But I can see the logs like this:

`---try send file:D:/file_upload/1464578330791_user.jpg`

It seems that the file has been fetched, but the `res.sendFile` does not complete its job.

Also, when I tried `/download/1`, the file can be downloaded.

What's going on ?

Comment: `res.sendFile() is supported by Express v4.8.0 onwards` http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile

Comment: The `id` variable in your route is undefined. Are you posting the full code? Also, `fullpath` in `doServeFile` will _always_ evaluate to true because you're prefixing it with `Config.uploadDest + "/"`.

Comment: @robertklep: My misspell, the id is not undefined. And as I said, I can see the full path of the file in the log.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue the other day and found that `sendFile` doesn't actually acknowledge absolute paths correctly and hangs. Setting the `root` option solved the issue. Hopefully it might work for you.

```
res.sendFile(fullpath, {root: '/'});
```

Comment: Is that a Windows thing? Absolute paths for just fine for me (OS X).

Comment: For me, this has occurred within Alpine and maybe Debian as well if I remember correctly.

Comment: Hmm weird, I can't reproduce it on Debian or Ubuntu either.

Comment: try res.download() it will download the file to client

Comment: @hguser If you add a callback as the third parameter do you receive an error object as in `function (err) {console.log(err);}`. If sendFile fails you still need to call `next` for your express route to return a result otherwise it will hang as well.

Answer (score 0):

After dig into the source codes of express, I found the answer.

When the `res.sendFile` is called, express will to make sure that the `root` of the path is set or the path must be an absolute path, check [this](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/4.13.4/lib/response.js#L402), it  is just the `isAbsolutepath` which cause this problem,[codes](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/4.13.4/lib/utils.js#L68-L71):

```
exports.isAbsolute = function(path){
  if ('/' == path[0]) return true;
  if (':' == path[1] && '\\' == path[2]) return true;
  if ('\\\\' == path.substring(0, 2)) return true; // Microsoft Azure absolute path
};
```

So a path like

`D:/a/a.txt` will not be treated as an absolute path!

`D:\\a\\a.txt` will be. And so does linux-like path `/home/a/a.txt`.

And this is how I build the path(manually), which is not an absolute path from express's perspective:

```
var fullPath = Config.uploadDest + "/" + file.path;
```

So I change it to:

```
var fullPath = path.join(Config.uploadDest,file.path);
```

It worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows operating system, use its full path such as

D:/folder1/folder2/index.html